# Any limit on Nesting of jobs in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

**I know that nesting of jobs is possible. But i want to know is there any limit on nesting     of jobs inside a job?**

Comment: I think this is a valid question, in the context of "Spring Batch" framework. The question is about - if there is any limitation for the depth of nested jobs. Please re-open this post..